# C++ Multidimensional string arrays

Tags: c++

Can someone please correct this code for me, so it can produce the correct output. 
The code is to display the name of the patient,
the doctor that treated him/her,
the room where he/she was treated.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string bisi[3][4] = {{"      ", "DOCTOR 1", "DOCTOR 2", "DOCTOR 3"},
{"ROOM 1", "AFUAH", "ARABA", "JOHNSON"},
{"ROOM 2", "BENJAMIN", "KOROMA", "CHELSEA"}};

    for (int row=0; row<3; row++){
        for (int col=0; col<4; col++){
            cout<<bisi [row][col]<<" "; /*I get error on this line.The angle bracket "<<" Error Message: No operator matches this operand.*/
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you identify what each element of `bisi` is supposed to mean please (and what their relation ship should be).  Perhaps show us the output you want to see.

Comment: I accept this as a beginner's test program. But note that idiomatic C++ would not model a patient / doctor / room relationship in a multidimensional (C...) array like this. You would have `class Doctor`, `class Patient`, ...

Comment: if you're using c++ take advantage of its functionality and library. use a vector. if not just use plain C.

Comment: I am still a beginner please, i just need this done for an assignment given to me by my lecturer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to change:

```
cout << bisi[row] << bisi[col] << " ";
```

to:

```
 cout << bisi[row][col] << " ";
```

`bisi` is a 2d array, `bisi[row]` or `bisi[col]` will just print you an address

Comment: i used cout << bisi[row][col] << " ";     but i get this "<<" error  @DimChtz

Comment: @Sir_Martins Can you update the question with the new code and the error you get?

Comment: I changed my data type from "string" to "int" the code worked without error.

Answer (score 1):

From an object oriented view point, this is bad style. Wrap the information in a class. e.g.

```
struct Appointment
{
  std::string patient;
  std::string doctor;
  std::string room;
}
```

and store that information in some kind of collection:

```
std::vector<Appointment> appointments;
appointments.emplace_back({"henk", "doctor bob", "room 213"});
appointments.emplace_back({"jan", "doctor bert", "room 200"});
```

printing could then be done by:

```
for (const auto &appointment: appointments)
{
  std::cout << appointment.patient
            << appointment.doctor
            << appointment.room
            << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added the preprocessor directive #include <"string"> without the quotes and it worked fine.
Thank You guys for helping out.